# Why is the Amadeus traditional flight search (flight offers) API missing scheduled flights? e.g. EasyJet, Wizz Air, TUI?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, amadeus

I am using the test environment and checking on the results I get. On certain itineraries I get all scheduled flights. However, I can't seem to be able to output any EasyJet, Wizz Air, TUI flights. Those are only the ones I have noticed, I presume there's more missing. I double check my results against skyscanner.com. Therefore, if an itinerary only has an EasyJet scheduled flight, then I get no results. Here's an example;

```
import requests
from amadeus import Client, ResponseError

amadeus = Client(
    client_id = 'xxxxx',
    client_secret = 'xxxxx',
)

flight_list = []
try:
    response = amadeus.shopping.flight_offers.get(
        origin = 'LTN',
        destination = 'ATH',
        departureDate = '2020-02-13',
        adults = 1,
        nonStop = 'true',
        currency = 'GBP',
    )


for resp in response.data:
        for offer in resp['offerItems']:

            flt_data = {
                'From' : offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['departure']['iataCode'],
                'To' : offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['arrival']['iataCode'],
                'Departure Date' : offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['departure']['at'][0:10],
                'Departure Time' : offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['departure']['at'][11:19],
                'Arrival Date' : offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['arrival']['at'][0:10],
                'Arrival Time' : offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['arrival']['at'][11:19],
                'Price' : offer['price']['total'][0:],
                'Terminal' : offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['departure']['terminal'],
                'Airline' : offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['carrierCode'],
                'Flight No.' : str(offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['carrierCode']) + ' ' + str(offer['services'][0]['segments'][0]['flightSegment']['number'])
            }

        flight_list.append(flt_data)

    print(flight_list)

except ResponseError as error:
    print(error)
```

With the following output;

```
[origin/destination/date(s) combination] No fare found for requested itinerary
```

I can confirm that the script runs fine when none of the above airlines are scheduled to operate the itinerary I search for. Would really appreciate your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

This API doesn't include low-cost carriers for the moment. This is part of our backlog and will be deliver later.

Comment: Many thanks for letting me know. Is this something that changes once I transition from the test environment to the enterprise environment?